# Adding Firebase Analytics to project

Tags: swift, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I am trying to add Firebase to my project like I have done many times before. But for some reason I am now getting:

```
[!] Error installing FirebaseAnalytics

[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/ch/gnysjzrx1clg0knrf1v2s89h0000gn/T/d20200507-17062-csc5bj/file.tgz https://dl.google.com/dl/cpdc/ade56e7282932673/FirebaseAnalytics-6.5.0.tar.gz --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

---------------------

curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to dl.google.com:443
```

This error occurs when ever I try to add either "Firebase/Analytics" or just "Firebase".

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your Podfile?

Comment: Intermittent network failure?